# Using XSLT, how can I select only elements with a certain attribute value?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML that looks something like this:

```
<Assessment xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" GUID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <Data ID="4543" DateCreated="2020-02-18T09:22:31.743">
    <Questions>
      <Question ID="120" RowNumber="1" ElementName="E147" ElementType="DropDownList" Type="a32c5590-cd7c-4b1f-8df5-592cd243e0e0" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Foo Hours</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer ID="718" Type="a32c5590-cd7c-4b1f-8df5-592cd243e0e0">
            <Text>.25</Text>
          </Answer>
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="121" RowNumber="2" ElementName="E121" ElementType="CheckBoxList" Type="22c5e458-d3ff-4f45-b669-ba0ec8f3703d" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Foo</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer ID="739" Type="22c5e458-d3ff-4f45-b669-ba0ec8f3703d">
            <Text>This is some text</Text>
          </Answer>
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="122" RowNumber="3" ElementName="E142" ElementType="TextBox" Type="" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Other</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer Type="Assessment6" Qualifier="E142">
            <Text>42</Text>
          </Answer>
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="123" RowNumber="4" ElementName="E148" ElementType="DropDownList" Type="a32c5590-cd7c-4b1f-8df5-592cd243e0e0" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Bar Hours</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="124" RowNumber="5" ElementName="E122" ElementType="CheckBoxList" Type="3d29c234-99de-4ba1-a8a1-a3e20a6e880c" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Bar </Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="125" RowNumber="6" ElementName="E123" ElementType="TextBox" Type="" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Other</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="126" RowNumber="7" ElementName="E149" ElementType="DropDownList" Type="a32c5590-cd7c-4b1f-8df5-592cd243e0e0" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Baz Hours</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="127" RowNumber="8" ElementName="E124" ElementType="CheckBoxList" Type="5b6901f2-2e52-483b-9b4c-9426744c1076" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Baz</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
      <Question ID="128" RowNumber="9" ElementName="E125" ElementType="TextBox" Type="" Required="false" IncludeComment="false">
        <Text>Other</Text>
        <Answers>
          <Answer />
        </Answers>
      </Question>
    </Questions>
  </Data>
</Assessment>
```

I want to select all the `Question` tags that have `ElementType` attribute values of `DropDownList` and add up their values. So I tried this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Data/Questions/Question[@ElementType=DropDownList]/Answers/Answer/Text)" />
```

But I get zero for some reason. If I leave out the `[@ElementType=DropDownList]` conditional, I get `NaN` which indicates that all values are being summed, including the text values. So something's wrong with this conditional, but I'm not sure what...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out; I need quotes around the value I'm testing:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Data/Questions/Question[@ElementType='DropDownList']/Answers/Answer/Text)" />
```